# how to get from database the last inset id before insert

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How to select the last insert id from database table

i need to get the last insert id from database

i try the `last_insert_id()` function but this doesn't work for me because i want to get this id before i do an insert query and when i get this id i do an insert query

i try to use `max` for the id but this have a problem that if i have a deleted 
id it will not be taken

> example if i have id 10 deleted than the max id will be 9 but the auto
>   increment will be 11

than i want to have the new id that will be added by the auto increment

> example:i have an id 10 deleted i want to take than next id it will be
>   11

Comment: Is this to fill in holes between ID sequences? If so, just don't bother.

Comment: why `last_insert_id()` didn't work for you?

Comment: Make sure you use transactions. Otherwise even if you manage to get the now_insert_id somehow it'll screw things up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You Can :

```
    SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name'
    AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'table_name';
```

And get your last id.

Comment: what i information_schema.tables   what is table_schema ?

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA is a database come with mysql by default
[check mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html), you will find the info that you want, why not execute it instead of setting a -1

Answer (score 1):

The autoincrement value is generated by the database itself, when the insertion is done ; which means you cannot get it before doing the actual insert query.
    insert some half-empty data
    get the autoincrement value that's been generated
    do your calculations, using that autoincrement value
    update the row to put the new / full data in place -- using the autoincrement generated earlier in the where clause of the update query, to identify which row is being updated.

```
As pseudo-code :
begin transaction
insert into your table (half empty values);
$id = get last autoincrement id
do calculations
update set data = full data where id = $id
commit transaction
```

or you may follow [Using Auto-Increment value in MYSQL Before Insert Trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24404540/using-auto-increment-value-in-mysql-before-insert-trigger)

Comment: `which means you cannot get it before doing the actual insert query` isn't correct.. See ahammar's answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can not and should not get the last inserted id before insert.

And there is not a single reason to do so. Just insert your data, get the actual id, and use it anywhere else. As simple as that.

Comment: You *always* can do that.