problem the concat isn't working properly in trigger in phpmyadmin mysql database xampp
I want to create new column from concating two columns. So I created a trigger to do that before inserting new row.
ex:



student_type
student_id
student_username




student
1
student_1



the type column is a manual inserting. id is primary key on Auto increment. username is nullable value.
the problem is that the username column still null.
the trigger:

the table after few tries:

note that the first value was inserted by me
I tried to switch the trigger to be after the insert but this is not allowed. If you can help me to make the trigger to concat the values correctly .Or another way to make the column be type_id automatically.

Is student_id a column name in your table? In your example the column is only called id

@nevada_scout yes its. It was mistake. its corrected now.  thank you
note: It has nothing to do with the problem because I used the correct names in the code.

Can you give some more info about the schema? What is the type of  each of the three columns? Are they all varchar, or is student_id an integer?

Instead of doing this with a trigger, why not do it with a generated column?

Is student_id an AUTO_INCREMENT column? You can't use NEW.student_id to get the value that will be assigned to it in a BEFORE INSERT trigger.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24404540/using-auto-increment-value-in-mysql-before-insert-trigger for how you can get the value that will be used.

the student_id is int, student_user_type is varchar, the student_username is varchar also
@nevada_scout Sorry for being late too

what is generated column. can you give me references/ answers to check it
@Barmar Sorry for being late too

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html
