# MySQL, automatic update a field after insert, based on id and prefix

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create in MySQL a 'custom' unique ID based on existing primary key (auto-incremented) 'id' field

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER update_id AFTER INSERT ON test 
BEGIN
    UPDATE test SET PN="PN-"+NEW.id;
END;
//
delimiter ;
```

I am using PhpMyAdmin and I really don't know if it's a UI problem (I encountered some problems in the past while creating triggers in PhpMyAdmin) or I really do something wrong.

What I need is a custom PN field that is automatically updated when insert new records in table, based on some text prefix "PN-"

```
id    PN    other fields
-------------------------
...
...
...
1253  PN-1253
1254  PN-1254

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
        UPDATE test SET PN="PN-"+NEW.id;
    END' at line 2
```

I read in some other StackOverflow post that this will be impossible (to update) on the same table AFTER insert.

There is a solution with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the new value and add it before insert

```
   delimiter //
    CREATE TRIGGER update_id BEFORE INSERT ON test 
    BEGIN
        SET @pn:= ( SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT 
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                        WHERE TABLE_NAME='test'
                          AND TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() ); 
      SET new.PN= CONCAT('PN-',@pn);
    END;
    //
    delimiter ;
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342853/update-table-column-after-insert-new-record-using-mysql-triggers)

Comment: May be a silly question, this is safe for multi user that asynchronously may obtain the ID from schema, then insert?

Comment: @user1797147 What is  async in your case?This will work for multi users,exactly what the db was designed for,