# MariaDB move data to another table with TRIGGER

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i want to move my current data to another table when the update value is "jakarta"

```
IF NEW.alamat = "jakarta" THEN
    INSERT INTO detail_mhs_copy1
    SELECT * FROM detail_mhs WHERE id_mhs = NEW.id_mhs;
    
    DELETE FROM detail_mhs WHERE id_mhs = OLD.id_mhs;
END IF;
```

but with this trigger its make error like this 
1442 - Can't update table 'detail_mhs' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

any solutions?

Comment: Non-solvable in trigger format. You may copy the rows to the "another table" and mark current record as one which must be deleted (by setting some special value in some column). The deletion itself must be performed by event procedure.

Comment: Alternatively you may prohibit direct data access and use stored procedure only. This allows to realize any complex logic in SP.

Comment: Another problem is i dont have acces to changes the action update

Comment: If so then trigger + event seems to be the only option.

Comment: What, exactly, do you need done?  Perhaps 2 things:  (1) copy OLD row to the other table and (2) allow the current table to be updated.  Or did you want the current row not to be changed?  Or maybe delete the current row?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below trigger and change col1 & col2 with your column's name and change primary key with column name which have primary key and not updating.

> DELIMITER $$
>
> CREATE TRIGGER detail_mhs_trig
> AFTER **UPDATE ON detail_mhs** FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
> IF **NEW.alamat = "jakarta"** THEN
> INSERT INTO detail_mhs_copy1(col1,col2, alamat)
> VALUES(old.col1, old.col2, new.alamat);
> END IF; END$$
>
> DELIMITER ;

Comment: I think its not solved my problem for deleteing current row in detail_mhs

Comment: you can't achieve this in single trigger which means, trigger can't change same table. Please have a look on below link and find solution

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342853/update-table-column-after-insert-new-record-using-mysql-triggers